# How to convert an English sentence that contains 'all and only' into predicate calculus sentence

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have the the following English sentence that I need to convert into a sentence in predicate logic:

> All and only spartans are bold

I'm not sure if it is simply: $∃x [B(x) ↔ S(x)]$ or whether this doesn't entail that 'all' spartans are bold, just that 'only' spartans are bold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rephrase it in English like this: For all individuals x, the individual is Spartan if and only if the individual is bold. So in logic, it would be:
$\forall x [B(x) \Leftrightarrow S(x)]$.

Your statement says something only about a single $x$ existing, not about all of them.

Comment: Thank you, I actually wrote out my original comment wrong 'I'm not sure if it is simply: ∃x[B(x)↔S(x)]' - meant to write ∀x[B(x)↔S(x)] which is what you have suggested anyway! Good to have it confirmed

Answer (score 0):

"All Spartans are bold" is $\forall x\mathrm{\ Spartan }(x)\implies\mathrm{ Bold}(x)$, and "Only Spartans are bold" is $\forall x\mathrm{\ Bold }(x)\implies\mathrm{ Spartan}(x)$. Hence we have:

$\forall x\mathrm{\ Spartan }(x)\iff\mathrm{ Bold}(x)$.

Comment: Thank you, I actually wrote out my original comment wrong 'I'm not sure if it is simply: ∃x[B(x)↔S(x)]' - meant to write ∀x[B(x)↔S(x)] which is what you have suggested anyway! Good to have it confirmed